# Is there an EVM compiler that supports coroutines? (e.g. generator functions)

Tags: evm, compilation, compiler, function

With coroutine I mean a subroutine that can be paused and resumed from another subroutine; preserving its internal state across pauses and resumes.

For example, a feature similar to:

- Javascript's `function*` & `yield`
- C++'s `co_await` & `co_yield`

Is there any language that supports something like this AND can compile to EVM code?

Answer (score 0):

As of jan 2022, there is no EVM compiler that supports generator functions.

Fingers crossed for the future